# Progressive Web App - OAuth Login - Not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, oauth, progressive-web-apps

## PWA OAuth Login

### Problem:

I have a `PWA` application which needs user authentication via `Facebook/OAuth`.
The problem is that the `OAuth` mechanism works in every circumstances but `iPhone/Standalone`.

I need to find out some way to make a `PWA` application works with `Facebook/OAuth` on `iPhone`. Is it possible? `Yes`/`No`?

### Sample Project:

I created a sample project:

https://github.com/napolev/pwa-oauth-login

based on the article:

https://medium.com/@jonnykalambay/progressive-web-apps-with-oauth-dont-repeat-my-mistake-16a4063ce113

**For simplicity**, on this sample project, I replaced the `Facebook/OAuth` mechanism with a simple `Custom/OAuth` mechanism.

### Code Preview:

**index.html**

```
<script>
...
window.open(
    url_oauth + '?url_callback=' + encodeURIComponent(url_callback),
    'Login Flow',
    'width=350,height=250'
);
...
window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    token.innerText = e.data.token;
})
...
</script>
...
<div>
    Token: <span id="token">...</span>
</div>
```

**callback.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// redirected to this page from the OAuth page
...
var data = {
    token: ...,
};
window.opener.postMessage(data, ...);
window.close();
...
</script>
```

If I connect my `Mac` to my `iPhone` and do `Remote Debugging`, I can see that when the method above: `window.close();` gets called, it throws the following warning, which makes me feel very pesimistic about my possibilities:

> Can't close the window since it was not opened by JavaScript

About the call: `window.opener.postMessage(...)` that's another story and right now I don't have enough information about why is not sending
the token to the opener window. Probably it is because a similar issue as with: `window.close();`.

### Highlights:

I did a series of experiments and all of them came out fine, but the case: `iPhone/Standalone` which failed because, even though a shorcut is added
to the home screen successfully and when you click it the app is opened properly without address bar, when the user clicks
the button: `Start OAuth flow` a new window is opened, this time with an address bar (`github.io`). Then, when the user clicks
the link: `[APP-CALLBACK]`, the user is redirected to a the app callback url but this window doesn't send back the token to the opener
window and also it doesn't get closed. If I do this experiment on `Android/Standalone`, this works fine. On top of that, on the same
`iPhone` with `Safari` (but not standalone) it works properly. The only problem I'm facing is on `iPhone/Standalone` as you can see
on the following animated image.

Please, check the `Experiments` section below for more details.

[image: screenshot]

### Project Download:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/napolev/pwa-oauth-login
$ cd pwa-oauth-login
$ npm i
$ npm run start
```

### Test:

On your `iPhone` (another device on the same network), go to:

```
http://[YOUR-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS]:4000
```

### Installing as Standalone:

**Android / Google Chrome** - Click on the highlighted option to install the app as standalone.

[image: screenshot]

**iPhone / Safari** - Click on the highlighted icons to install the app as standalone.

[image: screenshot]

### Experiments:

1- `2018-11-24 00:10 GMT`. On this commit, the `OAuth` flow behaves as follows:

```
Windows + Chrome → SUCCESS
Windows + Firefox → SUCCESS
Windows + Edge → SUCCESS

Android + Chrome → SUCCESS
Android + Standalone → SUCCESS

Mac + Chrome → SUCCESS
Mac + Safari → SUCCESS

iPhone + Chrome → SUCCESS
iPhone + Safari → SUCCESS
iPhone + Standalone → !!! FAILURE !!!
```

Comment: Your problem is that you cannot associate a custom url scheme to a web shortcut added to the home screen for use as the callback URL.  Using a "http/s" URL as you are doing results in the callback being opened in the current Safari environment.  The only way you might get it to work is if you can open the OAuth page in your current web view, not in a new window.

Comment: I just tried: `document.location.href = ...` instead of: `window.open(...)` and it also opened Safari out of the standalone mode. I think it does that because it is another domain. But the point is that the `OAuth` service will always be on a different domain, so I start thinking that it is not possible to do `OAuth` with `PWA` on `iPhone`. What do you think?

Comment: I agree.  That is why I said "you might get it work".  To be honest if you want to deliver a native app experience on iOS you have to write a native app.  I don't think Apple is really a big fan of PWA

Comment: Any new findings? I am highly interested in this as it seems to be one of the major negative points in my case too.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to embed an iframe for the oauth flow?

Comment: Or just tell the user to close the browser in standalone mode? that would be the biggest negative point, as far as I understood?

Comment: @Tobias any findings?

Comment: @AlexeiS. nope, i think this is not possible.

Comment: @Tobias So basically Apple doesn't provide any solution so far for redirection to saved web-apps (pwa's) nor has there been a known work-around so far, right? Thanks for your inputs anyway!

Comment: Just an FYI - the new version of IOS 12.2 fixes this, you can now successfully use 0auth in a PWA

Comment: I'm using firebase for oAuth in my PWA, seems like it still doesn't work for us 9IOS 12). Google / Facebook login are using oAuth redirect, so I was expecting it to work but....

Comment: On the contraty, I want the opposite

Comment: Hi David. Did you find a solution for this, please? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the manifest when loading the application on an iOS device as discussed here.

```
var iOS = !!navigator.platform && /i(Phone|Pad|Pod)/.test(navigator.platform);
if (iOS) {
    document.querySelector('link[rel="manifest"]').setAttribute("rel", "no-on-ios");
}
```

Comment: It did not work for iOS 12. I still get a new window and after login it remains in the same window.

Comment: Are you linking to the manifest file like so?

`<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />`

Answer (score 0):

What about using a server-side proxy, so the PWA never leaves its scope and the server does all the OAuth work in the background?

https://medium.com/@madumalt/oauth2-proxy-for-single-page-applications-8f01fd5fdd52

Comment: Has anyone being able to find a solution for the redirect issue on ios?